# Pandas: Normalizing all the values in one column between 0 and 10 based on groups present in another column

Tags: python, pandas, normalize

Suppose I have a dataframe like:

```
    Group  Values
0       1       1
1       1       4
2       1       2
3       1       7
4       1       3
5       2       4
6       2       1
7       2       5
8       2      12
9       2       4
10      2      10
11      3       2
12      3       6
13      3      20
14      3      15
```

MRE:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Group': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3], 'Values': [1, 4, 2, 7, 3, 4, 1, 5, 12, 4, 10, 2, 6, 20, 15]})
```

Notice in the dataframe that the group 1 has max value of 7, while group 2 has 12 and group 3 has 20. Now I want to normalize each `Group`'s `Values` to a cap value of 10.

I tried to use `pd.groupby` method but I'm left with no clue on how to proceed further. Plus I know I could use a `for` loop but this would be very inefficient as I have about 20k samples in the data I'm trying to work with.

Is there a sweet and subtle method which can do the trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `groupby` with `transform` for this. There's a similar example [in the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) of `transform()`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Group': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3], 'Values': [1, 4, 2, 7, 3, 4, 1, 5, 12, 4, 10, 2, 6, 20, 15]})

df['normal'] = df.groupby('Group').transform(lambda x: (x / x.max()) * 10)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    Group  Values     normal
0       1       1   1.428571
1       1       4   5.714286
2       1       2   2.857143
3       1       7  10.000000
4       1       3   4.285714
5       2       4   3.333333
6       2       1   0.833333
7       2       5   4.166667
8       2      12  10.000000
9       2       4   3.333333
10      2      10   8.333333
11      3       2   1.000000
12      3       6   3.000000
13      3      20  10.000000
14      3      15   7.500000
```

Comment: Nice one, didnt quite get the question initially, it makes sense now :) you can also grab the max in transform and do other operations outside (not sure if that would be more efficient) : `df['Values'].div(df.groupby("Group")['Values'].transform('max')).mul(10)` +1

Comment: Thanks for the simple answer. Just wondering would this still work if I had one more column with `strings` (say) in the dataframe?

Comment: NVM I figured, `df['normal'] = df[['Group', 'Values']].groupby('Group').transform(...)`. Thanks again for the help:)